# Meteor JS: obscene amount of data loaded in loop

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an app that loads a Jobs collection

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
  var onet = Session.get('currentIndustryOnet');
  var city_id = Session.get('currentMapArea');
  jobsSubscription = Meteor.subscribe('jobs', onet, city_id);

  console.log(onet);

  if(jobsSubscription.ready) {
    Session.set('jobCount', Jobs.find().count());
  }
});

Template.selector.events({
  'click div.select-block ul.dropdown-menu li': function(e) {
    var selectedIndex = $(e.currentTarget).attr("rel");
    var val = $('select#industryPicker option:eq(' + selectedIndex + ')').attr('value');
    var oldVal = Session.get('currentIndustryOnet');

    if(val != oldVal) {
      Session.set('jobsLoaded', false);
      Session.set('currentIndustryOnet', val);
    }
  }
});
```

The `console` logs 20+ values for what the var `onet` is. It appears that `Meteor.autorun` doesn't run just once. Is this normal? If not, how do I fix this to only run once?

Updated:

```
Jobs = new Meteor.Collection('jobs');
Cities = new Meteor.Collection('cities');
Pagination.style('bootstrap');

Session.setDefault('jobCount', null);
Session.setDefault('jobsLoaded', false);

Meteor.subscribe('cities');

Session.set('jobCount', Jobs.find().count());

Deps.autorun(function(){
  var onet = Session.get('currentIndustryOnet');
  var city_id = Session.get('currentMapArea');
  Meteor.subscribe('jobs', onet, city_id, function onReady(){
    Session.set('jobsLoaded', true);
  });

  Session.set('jobCount', Jobs.find().count());
});

function plotCities() {
  console.log("CITIES PLOTTING");
  // var jobs = Jobs.find().fetch();
  // var addresses = _.chain(jobs)
  //             .countBy('address')
  //             .pairs()
  //             .sortBy(function(j) {return -j[1];})
  //             .map(function(j) {return j[0];})
  //             .slice(0, 50)
  //             .value();

  // gmaps.clearMap();
  // $.each(_.uniq(addresses), function(k, v){
  //   var addr = v.split(', ');

  //   Meteor.call('getCity', addr[0].toUpperCase(), addr[1], function(error, city){
  //     if(city) {
  //       var opts = {};
  //       opts.lng = city.loc[1];
  //       opts.lat = city.loc[0];
  //       opts.population = city.pop;
  //       opts._id = city._id;
  //       gmaps.addMarker(opts);
  //     }
  //   });
  // })
}

Template.list.jobs = function() {
  plotCities();
  return Pagination.collection(Jobs.find({}).fetch());
}
```

The `console.log('CITIES PLOTTING')` gets called around 8 times the first time the page loads and then if I switch the Sessioned onet, and the jobs reloads the data, the call is 30+ times

*Update 2:*

Here is my code:

```
Session.set('jobsLoaded', false);

Meteor.subscribe('cities');

Session.set('jobCount', Jobs.find().count());

Deps.autorun(function(){
  var onet = Session.get('currentIndustryOnet');
  var city_id = Session.get('currentMapArea');
  Meteor.subscribe('jobs', onet, city_id, function onReady(){
    Session.set('jobsLoaded', true);
  });

  Session.set('jobCount', Jobs.find().count());
});

function plotCities() {
  var jobs = Jobs.find().fetch();
  var addresses = _.chain(jobs)
              .countBy('address')
              .pairs()
              .sortBy(function(j) {return -j[1];})
              .map(function(j) {return j[0];})
              .slice(0, 50)
              .value();

  gmaps.clearMap();
  $.each(_.uniq(addresses), function(k, v){
    var addr = v.split(', ');

    Meteor.call('getCity', addr[0].toUpperCase(), addr[1], function(error, city){
      if(city) {
        var opts = {};
        opts.lng = city.loc[1];
        opts.lat = city.loc[0];
        opts.population = city.pop;
        opts._id = city._id;
        gmaps.addMarker(opts);
      }
    });
  })
}

Template.list.jobs = function() {
  if(Session.equals('jobsLoaded', true)) {
    console.log("LOADED PLOT");
    plotCities();
  }

  return Pagination.collection(Jobs.find({}).fetch());
}
```

When `console.log("LOADED PLOT")` is called... the first time it loads 8 times, the second, almost 40...

Comment: `Meteor.autorun()`? I don't even see that in the docs.

Comment: Sorry, typo. I mean `Deps.autorun()`

Answer (score 0):

`Deps.autorun` rerun whenever a reactive item used inside is updated. You've got three such items in your function: two session variables and `.ready()` handle. Most probably the last one is causing the multiple rerun. If you're certain that the session variables were not touched during that time, that's the only option.

While I'm not certain about this, `.ready()` might be invalidated each time a new item is pulled up in the subscription channel. So having this check inside your autorun would result in several initial reruns as the first batch of data is pulled.

Move that check outside of autorun (it's possible as the subscription is visible from outside) and the problem should be solved.

---

Ah, now it's something else: you're calling `plotCities` from `Template.list.jobs`, which is also reactive and get rerun each time something in `Jobs.find({})` changes – so again, each time a new initial item is loaded.

You've got a session variable in which you mark that your subscription is ready. Use it to filter the call:

```
Template.list.jobs = function() {
  if(Session.equals('jobsLoaded', true)) plotCities();
  return Pagination.collection(Jobs.find({}).fetch());
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your help with my questions about Meteor. I tried your suggestion but its still making a ton of calls. I have updated my answer to include new code I am trying

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong but this killing me... I updated my question with my new code...